# 5x4 dataset - How do you create unique sets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Hey thanks for checking this out for me. Here's my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XUTPaz_a7BK0h6S_fN5QaDNjhps9W-YM2qBz_ew8fnw/edit#gid=0)

A2:D6 is a simplified dataset I have. I need a formula to create the unique and ordered sets in F2:G4.

FYI: Over time, the letters will grow to D, E, F, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We first need all the Unique values in Column 1. We can do that very easily with the `UNIQUE` function.

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A)
```

Note that we are starting from A2, and not A1 to avoid including the header.

Next, the actual values.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(
    TEXTJOIN(
        ",",
        TRUE,
        QUERY(
            UNIQUE(FLATTEN(
                QUERY(
                    $A$2:$D,
                    "SELECT * WHERE A = '" & $J2 & "'",
                    0))),
        "SELECT * ORDER BY Col1",0)),
    "[a-zA-Z],",
    "")
```

The first step is to get all rows with the values in J2. J2 being the Unique values from the previous formula. Next we turn it all into one column using the `FLATTTEN` formula, then we remove all duplicates by using the `UNIQUE` function. We Query it again, just to sort all the values. Using `TEXTJOIN`, we can combine all the values into a text string. There is the letter still, but we can remove that using a RegEx. Specifically, `REGEXREPLACE`.

To increase the number of columns, go into the first `QUERY` function and change the range there. I don't think the second Query is needed, but unless it is necessary for you, then you can remove it. The `REGEXREPLACE` should find the letter still.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is amazing and so helpful! @David

Answer (score 2):

A perhaps simpler way is to use `filter()`, like this:

`=textjoin( ", ", true, sort( unique( flatten( filter(B$2:D, A$2:A = J2) ) ) ) )`

Like the accepted answer, the above formula needs to be filled down.

To create the whole result table in one go without the need to fill down, use the recently introduced lambda functions, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  labels, numbers, 
  { 
    unique(labels), 
    map( 
      unique(labels), 
      lambda( 
        label, 
        textjoin( ", ", true, 
          sort( unique( flatten( 
            filter(numbers, labels = label) 
          ) ) ) 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  } 
)(A2:A, B2:D)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XUTPaz_a7BK0h6S_fN5QaDNjhps9W-YM2qBz_ew8fnw/edit#gid=0).

Comment: This is definitely much simpler! Didn't realize that `SORT` could sort without all the other arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein to doubleunary's answer, to return both the groups and their values in one formula:

```
=lambda(group,{group,byrow(group,lambda(group,textjoin(", ",true,sort(unique(flatten(filter(B$2:D,A$2:A=group)))))))})(unique(filter(A$2:A,A$2:A<>"")))
```

N.B. I feel the inability of BYROW to spill a horizontal array per row makes the coding for these situations much more complicated than it needs to be...